# How to pass input value to entityset of odata from ui5 screen

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to pass a value from fiori screen to oData and want to read the entityset method.But when I check the debugger in odata the it_key_tab has zero records.

```
    onNext: function(oEvent) {
            var oViewModel = {};
            oViewModel.MBLNR = this.getView().byId("idMd").getValue();
            oViewModel.MJAHR = this.getView().byId("idFy").getValue();
            if (oViewModel.MBLNR === "") {
                var msg = ("Please Enter the material Doc No.");
                MessageToast.show(msg);
            } else
            if (oViewModel.MJAHR === "") {
                msg = ("Please Enter the fiscal year");
                MessageToast.show(msg);
            } else {
                var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
                var oFilter = new Filter("MBLNR", FilterOperator.EQ, oViewModel.MBLNR);
                //var oFilter1 = new Filter("MJAHR", FilterOperator.EQ, oViewModel.MJAHR);
                var aFilters = new Filter({
                    filters: [oFilter]
                });

                oModel.read("/MaterialDocReservationSet", null, {
                    filters: [aFilters],
                    //this.getView().getModel().read("/UserInputSet", oViewModel, {
                    success: function(OData, response) {},
                    error: function(OData, response) {
                        //MessageToast.show("Error");
                    }

                });
            }
```

Comment: I have created odata in which i have one entityset "MaterialDocReservationSet",in which key field are mblnr and rsnum.when i am entering value from ui5 screen it hits the Odata entityset but when i check in it_key_tab ,it has zero records in it.Please suggest how to capture entry in it_key_tab orit_filter_select_options inside entityset.

Comment: you do relise, that you give OData an array with an array inside which contains a filter? delete the [] around aFilters and try again, Also as long you just have one filter you do not need to put into an array at all, so just do smth like filters: oFilter;

Comment: actually i have to pass two filter as you can see one i have commented and was trying to test with one filter.Thats why i put filter in  array.I tried as you suggested above but still i am not getting the value inside IT_KEY_TAB inside get_entityset .

Comment: I just conclude you are using a SAP backend, with an OData service create with the SEGW since you are talking about the it_key_tab field,  the filters are not in the it_key_tab, this field is for when you get a single entity,  filters are found in IT_FILTER_SELECT_OPTIONS or IV_FILTER_STRING

Comment: also DO NOT use those parameters directly, always access them via the IO_TECH_REQUEST

Comment: i tried to implement IO_TECH_REQUEST_CONTEXT in entityset and run the ui5 application again with input but when it came inside odata entityset there are no entries received

Comment: but when i tested only with odata service its working perfect. 
 /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_TECHNICIAN_SRV/MaterialDocReservationSet?$filter=MBLNR eq 'xxxxxxxxx' or MJAHR eq 'xxxx'. But when i execute through UI5 i am not getting any records inside odata

Comment: open the batch in that ui5 sends , and post that, mb we see smth there that we missed (can be found in dev tools)

Answer (score 1):

In your oData read, remove null parameter. Also filters should be: filters: [oFilter].
Filters property can accept an array containing filter objects, in your code you have nested arrays and filters.

Answer (score 0):

In your front-end code, your are calling `oModel.read("/MaterialDocReservationSet", null, {...})`. According to the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read), you should be calling `read(sPath, {...})` (without your second parameter `null`).

In backend Gateway OData `GET_ENTITYSET` method, you should be accessing the filters using the filter methods of `io_tech_request_context`. `it_key_tab` has to do with the key in a `GET_ENTITY` (corresponding OData URI e.g. `MaterialDocReservationSet(1)`).